# How can I validate multiple text fields on submit form in fabric UI with reactJS and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote text fields like below in form tag. Both text fields call the same function. should I call  {this._getErrorMessage} multiple times in the same time

I declare function outside the form like below.this function checks null value.

```
    _getErrorMessage = (value: any) => {
    value.trim().length === 0 ? required : "" 
   }

    <Textfield
    id={AppIDConst`enter code here`ants.EMP_NAME}
    type={fieldPropertyConstants.TEXT}
    label={filedLabelConstants.EMP_NAME}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    required={true}
    validateOnLoad={false}
    onGetErrorMessage= {this._getErrorMessage}
/>

<Textfield
    id={AppIDConstants.EMP_ADHAR_NO}
    type={fieldPropertyConstants.NUMBER}
    label={filedLabelConstants.ADHAR_NUMBER}
    required={true}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    onGetErrorMessage= {this._getErrorMessage}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use submit validation instead of input validation, you'll need to add the validator function to the form instead.

```
onSubmit(form) {
  form.preventDefault();
  // retrieve form values and validate here...
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      // rest of form...
    </form>
  );
}
```

Remember to bind your form in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: I have done it like this <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitEmployeeDetails} >   onSubmitEmployeeDetails = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // other code }